# How can I send Dynamic Dropdown Value and option name in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to save a dynamic values (from api) to my localdb for offline processing. I have 2 fields, event_id and event_name in dropdown directly coming from the API.

```
<select name="event_id" class="form-control" id="change">
    <label>Select Live Event </label>
    <?php foreach($events as $event): ?>
        <option value="<?=$event->eventid;?>"> 
          <?=$event->name;?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Now I want user to select an event and save both event id and event name in local database. I know how to handle event_id but problem is event_name.. How do I assign a variable to this so that I could save both event_id and event_name at the same time.

Comment: you have to use jquery for this...

Comment: No you dont have to use jQuery, it can be done in pure PHP too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cant get the values from the database and HAVE to get it from the form, you could separate the values by a delimiter (which you know for sure doesnt appear in either your ID nor the name), semicolon for example.

```
            <select name="event_id" class="form-control" id="change">
                <label>Select Live Event </label>
                <?php foreach($events as $event): ?>
                    <option value="<?=$event->eventid . ';' . $event->name;?>"> 
                          <?=$event->name;?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
```

You can then take this value in PHP and explode it there:

```
$split = explode(';', $_POST['event_id']);
$id = $split[0];
$name = $split[1];
```

Make sure to check $split first if it has 2 elements so you can proceed.

---

If you CAN select the value from the database too, go for that.

Comment: Debatable if it is nice, but it works :)
As I said earlier, I would go for fetching the data from the database if that is possible

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt actually Im fetching events data from live api. I dont have offline database. I have to map these events with another api so to avoid maximum calls, I'm populating offline data and then mapping with user input. so getting from database isn't an option here as it doesnt exist at the moment.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can cache the results from the api in the database? Then run a cron maybe once a day (or how often your data changes) to populate the database. That way you have to fetch the data only once per day from the api.